# Query two row database

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables in a database
This is the Users table.
[Users Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqShi.png)
This is the UserGroups table.
[User Groups Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogd1T.png)
Currently I have this query.
`SELECT userID,name,email,role FROM swcr_users`

The problem is that I need to query the database to display the user. I want to select the group associated with a user. However, I want the query to display the group's name instead of the group id.

Comment: So the role column is an integer and you want it to display the name from a different table that you haven't told us the name of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select u.userID, u.name, u.email, r.title from _users u inner join swcr_roles r on (role=groupID);
```

I am assuming your roles table is called prefix_roles.